# Proofs of several parts of a theorem or of equivalent definitions

Tags: spacing, best-practices, amsthm

Often in mathematical texts there are theorems which either consist of several parts or state several equivalent conditions. When proving the theorem you make an own paragraph for each part of the theorem resp. for each implication of the equivalent conditions. My question is how to typeset this correctly. For example the naive approach

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand{\implication}[2]{\enquote{#1$\implies$#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
    We give two proofs of the first part of the theorem.

    (i) a a a a a a a a  aa a a a aa a a a a a aa  aa a a a aa a a a a a a a a.

    (i) asdöfjqwaüeigüirvüiv aegiaeüigjasdasfqüeignüigrjqi jüijgoirjgqüeoig jqüijqeijqeüij
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
    We give two proofs of the first implication.

    \implication{(i)}{(ii)} a a a a a a a a  a a a a aa  aa a a a aa a a a a a a a a.

    \implication{(i)}{(ii)} asdöfjqwaüeigüirvüiv aegiaeüigjüirjgirg qüeignüigrjqijüijgoirjgqie qüeoigjqüijqeijqeüij
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

leads to the behaviour that after the same item label (e.g. "(i)==>(ii)"), the text of the proof does not necessarily start at the same position in the line and the spacing inside the item label is also different:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being lucky in the first proof, because the spaces *seem* the same. They stretch or shrink differently for justification, exactly like in the second proof. What you need is fixed spaces, so you also need a box around the implication. Here I use `\enspace`, which is half of a quad.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand{\implication}[2]{%
  \enquote{\mbox{$\text{#1}\implies\text{#2}$}}%
  \enspace\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\statement}[1]{%
  #1\enspace\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
We give two proofs of the first part of the theorem.

\statement{(i)} a a a a a a a a  aa a a a aa a a a a a aa  
aa a a a aa a a a a a a a a.

\statement{(i)} asdöfjqwaüeigüirvüiv aegiaeüigjasdasfqüeignüigrjqi 
jüijgoirjgqüeoig jqüijqeijqeüij
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
We give two proofs of the first implication.

\implication{(i)}{(ii)} a a a a a a a a  a a a a aa  aa a a a 
aa a a a a a a a a.

\implication{(i)}{(ii)} asdöfjqwaüeigüirvüiv aegiaeüigjüirjgirg 
qüeignüigrjqijüijgoirjgqie qüeoigjqüijqeijqeüij
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Why is it preferable to have `#1` and `#2` include it the math environment together with `\text{}` ? Would it be possible to further format them, say making them italic (not that this is intended)? Or equipping them with hyperlinks to the statements inside the theorem? (I cannot try this out right now.)

Comment: @JohnDorian Once you have segregated them into a macro, you can do (almost) whatever you want. Why using a single math formula? Because it *is* a single math formula. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `\mbox` in your `\implication` macro which prevents LaTeX from adding space around the implication sign on the distribution of space between the words of a line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand{\implication}[2]{\mbox{\enquote{#1$\implies$#2}}}

\begin{document}\sloppy
\begin{proof}
    We give two proofs of the first part of the theorem.

    (i) a a a a a a a a  aa a a a aa a a a a a aa  aa a a a aa a a a a a a a a.

    (i) asdöfjqwaüeigüirvüiv aegiaeüigjasdasfqüeignüigrjqi jüijgoirjgqüeoig jqüijqeijqeüij
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
    We give two proofs of the first implication.

    \implication{(i)}{(ii)} a a a a a a a a  a a a a aa  aa a a a aa a a a a a a a a.

    \implication{(i)}{(ii)} asdöfjqwaüeigüirvüiv aegiaeüigjüirjgirg qüeignüigrjqijüijgoirjgqie \mbox{qüeoigjqüijqeijqeüij}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note: I couldn't reproduce your problem from your MWE, so I added `\sloppy` and another `\mbox` to get the effect from your screenshot).

Comment: Thank you. I have wondered quite often what `\mbox` actually does. And thank you for pointing me to `\sloppy`, I think this will be helpful for searching counterexamples. (Perhaps you could not reproduce my MWE because I compiled with XeLaTeX without mentioning so.)